# .HTAccess Configuration error?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my HTAccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^en-gb/(.*)$ /site/pages/default/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^en-us/(.*)$ /site/pages/default/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^en-au/(.*)$ /site/pages/default/$1 [QSA]
```

When I access my site in the following formats its fine: 
http://mywebsite.com/en-gb/news?query=blahblah
http://mywebsite.com/en-gb/news

But when I enter my site in the following format:
http://mywebsite.com/en-gb/news/

it gives me with an 500 Error, I don't understand why.

Update: Apache Error Log

```
[Wed Jun 10 17:29:40.722436 2015] [core:error] [pid 7528:tid 1644] [client 127.0.0.1:3439] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Jun 10 17:29:40.722436 2015] [core:error] [pid 7528:tid 1644] [client 127.0.0.1:3439] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your apache error_log say? Also the last 3 rules are the same? you should make that one rule.

Comment: @anubhava Hello there, 404 Error because the "http://mywebsite.com/en-gb/news" is a .HTML file and not a directory.

Comment: @PanamaJack Hello, Yes you are they are the same, but I will need this to separate content per country base on my script.

Comment: You can still do that in one rule `RewriteRule ^en-(gb|us|au)/(.*)$ /site/pages/default/$1 [QSA,L]` Also did you try using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` for the 404?

Comment: @PanamaJack I updated my post with the error Logs and thanks for the Rewrite snippet; however I don't understand what the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` does

Comment: @PanamaJack Sorry for a lot of comments, with your snippet all of my page redirects with HTAcess result in 404 Error.

Comment: @user3052975 yes you are right because I didn't put it as a non capturing group. It needed to be proceeded by `?:` however anubhava got you sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your rules and tweak your rule regex pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^en-(?:us|au|gb)/(.*)$ /site/pages/default/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It works perfectly without any issue :) You saved my day

Comment: Sorry for the additional comment but what is the recommended method for alot of redirect's for the same directory?

Comment: Whenever possible, it is better to combine multiple rules like I showed above.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I get this in my error log now: `AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.`

Comment: ok you can remove `[NC]` after `-f` though it worked for me on my Apache.